# How to test for GNU or BSD version of rm?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu, bsd

The GNU version of `rm` has a cool -I flag. From the manpage:

```
-I     prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively.   Less
          intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes
```

Macs don't:

```
$ rm -I scratch
rm: illegal option -- I
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
   unlink file
```

Sometimes people have `coreutils` (the GNU version) installed on Macs and sometimes they don't. Is there a way to detect this command line flag before proceeding? I'd like to have something like this in my bash_profile:

```
if [ has_gnu_rm_version ]; then
    alias rm="rm -I"
fi
```

Comment: I changed the title since I think the real question is "How can I best check for which of two versions of a core tool I have?" It isn't really about Mac versus Linux (closer maybe is BSD versus Linux, but even then, that's not your *real* question, I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say test the output of `rm -I` on a temp file, if it passes then use the alias

```
touch /tmp/my_core_util_check

if rm -I /tmp/my_core_util_check > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    alias rm="rm -I"
else
    rm /tmp/my_core_util_check;
fi
```

Comment: I'd just add `2>&1` to the "rm -I" test

Answer (score 11):

`strings /bin/rm | grep -q 'GNU coreutils'`

if $? is 0, it is coreutils

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend not starting down this road at all. Target your scripts to be as portable as possible, and only rely on flags/options/behaviors you can count on. Shell scripting is hard enough - why add more room for error?

You can check [the official POSIX website for their specifications of utility commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html). For example, [rm](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html).

Comment: Telemachus: I'm trying to put this in a `.bash_profile` I sync across my accounts on multiple computers. It'd be nice to use the `-I` flag if it exists.

Comment: @Kevin - in that case, my last bit of advice: Don't alias `rm` to anything. Use `rmi` or something else instead. (See comments here for some discussion: http://superuser.com/questions/31171/undo-the-linux-trash-command/31172#31172)

Comment: Excellent advice to not alias rm: you don't want to get in the habit of expecting to see a prompt, and then be on a foreign system and accidentally delete the wrong file.

Comment: Your "POSIX descriptions" link is timing out, ATM. Maybe it used to be the answer to my question: How do you "target your scripts to be as portable as possible, and only rely on flags/options/behaviors you can count on"? Is it safe to assume I can count on any POSIX shell feature/utility to be as portable as possible?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Thanks. I updated the links. I was talking about counting on the POSIX features of commands separate from the shell itself. For the shell itself, yes, use POSIX features if you want to be as portable as you can.

Comment: Crosschecking every command and option you use in a shell script with this link to ensure portability seems like a high effort task. Are there tools you use that "lint" shell scripts and warn about non-portable commands/options?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Yes, there are such tools. And, yes, portability for shell scripts is a high effort task. You should open your own question.

Answer (score 4):

You could always ask rm its version with `--version` and check to see if it says *gnu* or *coreutils* like this:

```
rm --version 2>&1 | grep -i gnu &> /dev/null
[ $? -eq 0 ] && alias rm="rm -I"
```

Comment: Corey: running the default Mac `rm --version` yields an `illegal option --` message and the script terminates.

Comment: Edited to put `2>&` after the `rm` command, this _should_ solve that problem. Let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -I &> /dev/null
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
    echo coreutils detected
else
    echo bsd version detected
fi
```

Comment: Oren: I ran this on a Mac with both versions of `rm`, and the script thought both versions were the BSD version.

Comment: @Kevin The GNU tools are often installed with a 'g' prefix on Macs, in order to avoid stepping on tools written for the BSD versions. Try `grm` maybe, though see my answer above.

Comment: Also, when you say "The script thought both versions...", how did you run this script against "both versions"? Just calling `rm` will pick up whichever one is earlier in your `PATH` (assuming they're both called `rm`.

Comment: Telemachus makes a good point. you could technically have both installed. perhaps address 'rm' directly by the path coreutils should use?

Comment: I might just be failing because 'rm -I' without any arguments will return a non-zero value in both cases.